# Encrypt my SharedPreference

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences

My application use two strings for password and PIN from SharedPreferences. I have the file Settings.java which load the settings layout.

```
package org.secure.sms;

import org.krto.sms.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements   OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


//private static final String KEY_EDIT_TEXT_PREFERENCE = "password";


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);

}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            finish();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, SecureMessagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}   }
```

and the settings.xml (lauout) is the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/password_title"
        android:key="@string/first_category">

      <EditTextPreference
            android:key="password"
            android:title="Password"
            android:summary="@string/password_define"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pass_title"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/password_provide"   
            android:defaultValue="Default_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

      </PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory
                    android:title="@string/pin_title"
                    android:key="@string/second_category">

      <EditTextPreference
                        android:key="pin"
                        android:title="PIN"
                        android:summary="@string/pin_define"
                        android:dialogTitle="@string/pin_title"
                        android:dialogMessage="@string/pin_provide"   
                        android:defaultValue="111"

                        />

      </PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory

android:title="Help"
android:layout="@layout/help"


/>
```

Also I load my SharedPreferences strings with a function into my app:

```
public String getPass(Context context)
{

    SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    final String PASSWORD = prefs.getString("password","DEFAULT");

    return PASSWORD;

}
```

How can I hash or encrypt my those two strings? Is there any hash function or must I some encrypt function?

I don't create the SharedPreferences with code but I get them from the settings.xml file where put them the default strings. How I can ecrypt them at the first place? and when I use them decrypt them?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create your own encryption code. I, personally, enjoy using encryption with checksum

Comment: How I encrypt the default strings into settings.xml? I must save the encrypted strings into settings.xml? Like a MD5, fow example? And them into my app code I must encrypt the user's input and check if it is the same with the encrypted pregerences?

Comment: Just run it through an encryptor when it is being set, and a decryptor when it is being checked.

Comment: I don't set them with code. If you see my code above, I have just write the default values into settings.xml. I didn't write any code to create the preferences

Comment: You are going to have to modify your code so that you can dynamically encrypt/decrypt the input strings. Just change your EditTextPreferences to EditText fields and work with the input values. There isn't some sort of built in way of encrypting it, at least not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

To perform strong hash encryption that cannot be decrypted back, use SHA-256 hash function:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digest.update(yourPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String passwordEncrypted = Base64.encodeToString(digest.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now `passwordEncrypted` string contains base64 presentation of `yourPassword`'s hash value and is easy to store in database, preferences or xml file.

To check whether password was entered correctly, just encode the input the same way and compare result with the hash string stored in preferences. If initial strings are equal, it is guaranteed that hash strings will also be equal.

For example, for "Default_password" result is `p1wNvKUcenG+jyIrzVNPxWuWZ5KBF8sXrHyD5CuXtbo=`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is easy to encrypt (or, as you intended: hash) the password on the fly. If your intent is to store a hash of the password (at least) in your `SharedPreference` storage file, then you'll need to create an additional `EditTextPreference` in the code (not the XML) in your fragment creation code, and hide the real password `Preference`, like this:

```
        // Remove the password from the displayed list of preference, since the password is
        // computed from clear text
        PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
        Preference pref = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("password"); // <= This is the true password preference key your application is using
        screen.removePreference(pref);

        // And add a preference to the list to let the user enter the "clear text" password
        EditTextPreference password = new EditTextPreference(pref.getContext());
        password.setKey("passclear");
        password.setTitle("Password on the server");
        password.getEditText().setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        password.getEditText().setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        password.setDialogTitle("Password");
        password.setSummary(getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().getString("password", "").length() > 0 ? "***" : "None");
        // Update the summary dynamically so it either display "None" or a fake password
        password.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                preference.setSummary(newValue.toString().length() > 0 ? "***" : "None");
                return true;
            }
        });
        screen.addPreference(password);
```

Then, in your `PreferenceActivity@onDestroy` handler, you'll need to hash the value of the `passclear` preference to the true `password` preference, and remove the `passclear` preference like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Compute the hashed password here
    String password = "", stringValue = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("passclear", "");
    if (stringValue.length() > 0) {
        try {
            password = computeHash(stringValue, getSalt());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            password = "";
        }
    }

    // Remove the clear password preference
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    // Save the password in the preference now
    if (password.length() > 0) editor.putString("password", password);
    // And remove the clear text so it does not appear in the xml file anymore
    editor.remove("passclear");
    editor.apply();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "hashing" the password wouldn't be a good choice in this case, as you might need to decrypt it later to do some sort of server side validation. You can use a hash algorithm in the server side. 
Here's an example on how to do that.https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/

Instead of hashing you could encode your password, just to make sure that it won't be stolen by simply looking at your preferences file. To do so, I recommend you to use Base64 as it's really simple to use.

Here's an example

```
private String encode(String normalText) {
  return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(text.getBytes()));
}

private String decode(String encodedText) {
  return new String(Base64.decodeBase64(text.getBytes()));
}
```